# why julia Pkg.add failed on a CentOS server?

Tags: centos, julia, hpc, julia-pkg

I am not root user of a HPC, where I install julia on my own path and I want to add some julia packages like Plots. However when using Pkg.add, it cannot connect to the target website

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you completely sure the server is not network isolated? Could you run `curl https://github.com` and `curl https://pkg.julialang.org/registries` in a remote session and check whether any errors show up?

Comment: It reports error: curl: (35) SSL connect error. But I can install julia through `wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.7/julia-1.7.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`

Comment: As far as I remember Julia uses external system tools to download files. It seems that they have misconfigred certificates. I would try `sudo yum update`

Comment: But I am not a root user

Comment: @XuFe we can't do much without more information about the system. Possible explanations are bad root certificates on the machine or bad system clocks, among others. I would probably contact your system administrator, since this doesn't seem to be Julia's fault.